# How may I include a custom font into an HTML website?

Tags: html, css, web, font-face, truetype

Here's how I tried to include a font in my HTML project:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Commodore';
  url('Commodore-64-v6.3.ttf') format('truetype');
}
p {
  font-family: Commodore;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Font Family Test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The specified ttf font is in the same directory as the CSS and HTML files, but is not used? Instead it's using some Times -like font. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the right syntax of `@font-face` Try below

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Commodore';
    src: url('Commodore-64-v6.3.ttf') format('truetype');
 }
 p {
   font-family: Commodore;
 }
```

You can read more about `@font-face` [here](https://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)

Comment: That definitly was one mistake. I'm using src:, now. But it's working neither.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `src:` before `url` like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'YourFontName'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('../fonts/font.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}
```

Also, put your font in the "fonts" folder.

Comment: I put the font into the same folder as the other files, not having to hassle with slashes, backslashes or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The best and most convenient way of including fonts is via the Google Fonts API as follows:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Just apply this font via:

```
P {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```